# Handling multiple Classes with Types in client code

Tags: java, generics, type-safety, java-5

Suppose if I have the following classes

```
class A {} 
class B {} 

abstract class ParentClass<T> {
    abstract void accept(T t);
} 

class Child1 extends ParentClass<A> {
    void accept(A a) {} 
} 

class Child2 extends ParentClass<B> {
    void accept(B b) {} 
}
```

Now if I have a client code where I want to have both instances of child1 and child2 mapped to a string in a map (and) also make use of accept method, seems its impossible and I get it why. Is there a Better work around?

My client code looks like,

```
class Client {
    Map<String, ParentClass<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Client() {
       map.put("C1", new Child1());
       map.put("C2", new Child2());
    } 

    void callAccept(String type, Object o) {
        map.get(type).accept(o); //error
    } 

}
```

#Update 1
Adding the return type in the example as I missed when I typed the question from mobile.

Comment: Return type of `accept` is missing. Also there is no diamond in `new Child1()` as the class isn't parametrized. Strange that copying code from your computer to SO changes so much things ;)

Comment: Your `accept` does not have a return type. Additionally, you are losing some type safety here. One thing you could do would be to have your accept method take `Objects` and you check for the specific type in the implementations of  `Child1` and `Child2`. You could also have `A` and `B` implement a common interface to use in your map. It all depends on what you want to exactly achieve and how you want to use that map though.

Comment: @azro, I didn't copy code from my computer. I typed the question from my mobile.

Comment: Are you really using Java 5 still?

Comment: @Andy Turner, no I'm using Java 8. I added Java 5 tag as Generics was introduced in this version.

Comment: Given that Java 5 is now 17 years old, I think it can be assumed that generics are a given. You only need to add such an old version of there is something peculiar that requires only using Java 5 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Better" depends on what you want to achieve. As I understand your question, you just want to be able to compile the code and understand it. Many variations are possible, and "best" would depend on the business problem you are addressing.

Absent a business problem that the code might address, here is code that compiles without error. I fixed several errors in your code:

```java
// ParentClass.java

class Base {}
class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}

abstract class ParentClass<T> {
   abstract ParentClass<?> accept(Base base);
}

class Child1 extends ParentClass<A> {
  /* No idea what this is supposed to do, 
     so just return something type-compatible */
  ParentClass<A> accept(Base base) { return this; }
}

class Child2 extends ParentClass<B> {
  /* No idea what this is supposed to do, 
     so just return something type-compatible */  
  ParentClass<B> accept(Base base) { return this; }
}
```

`ParentClass`, a container, is subclassed as `Child1` and `Child2`.

`Base` above is a base class for the payload contained within `ParentClass` subclasses. You need a base class for the payload because the container class (`ParentClass`) is subclassed, and you want to be able to mix and match payloads.

```java
// Client.java

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Client {
  Map<String, ParentClass<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

  public Client() {
     map.put("C1", new Child1());
     map.put("C2", new Child2());
  }

  void callAccept(String type, Base base) {
      map.get(type).accept(base);
  }
}
```

Java, Scala, Haskell and other languages use [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory), specifically [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) to define precisely what is allowable. Practically speaking, and without getting lost in math, the general guidelines above are a few of the considerations for working with generics.

For more information, please read the section on generic containers in “Effective Java” by Joshua Bloch. I don't believe he mentions category theory, which is good.

If you are interested in "just enough" type theory, read about [covariant types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

Comment: Problem here is accept method should still accept T in the ParentClass and not Base. I've seen code written this way in some codebase and in the client code, they are using Raw types in the map just to avoid the error in the statement when calling the accept method.... where as  I have used wildcard in the example just to showcase the problem .

Comment: As I said, many permutations are possible. You asked a very general question, and entire books have been written about this subject.